# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'product')”

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am trying to read Shopify product page tags and ID's within Shopify's post-purchase script.

You don't need to be familiar with Shopify to understand this problem I am facing. It feels to be a Javascript problem and I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to reference these variables or objects.

Please read Shopify's docs [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/promoting-marketing/analyze-marketing/pixel-tracking-post-purchase-page) on the variables I can access.

My code

```
// Cart variables
var cartTagsString = "";
var cartProductIDString = "";

// Convert array of product tags into string
window.Shopify.order.lineitem.product.tags.forEach(function (item, index) {
cartTagsString = cartTagsString + item;
});

// Convert array of product id's into string
window.Shopify.order.lineitem.product.forEach(function (item, index) {
cartProductIDString = cartTagsString + item.id;
});
```

The error

```
“VM1370:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'product')”
```

Going to the exact line the error happens, it takes us here:

```
window.Shopify.order.lineitem.product.tags
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation might actually be wrong in this case.

There is a table of properties which has something called `lineItem` (which is different from `lineitem` by the way, case matters).  But the *code samples* show a property called `lineItems`.  And even in that table it *describes* `lineItem` as "the line items for the order", which implies an array.

Going with the code samples, your `forEach` would be something like this:

```
window.Shopify.order.lineItems.forEach(function (item, index) {
    cartTagsString = cartTagsString + item.id;
});
```

*Within* that `forEach` call, each `item` is an element in that array.  And `item` should have a property called `product` if you need to access that.

---

As for your first call to `forEach`, I don't see anything on that page which has a `tags` property.  But the structure would be the same.  For example, if any given `item` has a `tags` array, then you'd access that for the `item`.  For example:

```
window.Shopify.order.lineItems.forEach(function (item, index) {
    cartTagsString = cartTagsString + item.id;
    item.tags.forEach(function (tag) {
        // do something with the tag
    });
});
```

---

You might reach out to the vendor to ask them to clarify the documentation.  But just as a debugging step, if all else fails you can always `console.log` an object to observe what properties it has.  Documentation is written by humans, and humans make mistakes.  (Or perhaps written by someone who doesn't natively speak the language of the documentation and may mix up syntax from time to time.)

Comment: It is a bit confusing because the documentation Jack referenced shows "The following table contains the type definitions for the attributes that are exposed to post-purchase additional scripts through window.Shopify:"  and in the table below under orders it says: "lineItem The line items for the order."

Comment: @JoshuaCraven: Good catch, I guess I stopped at the code samples.  Sounds like the documentation is wrong.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, David for the response. Yes, Joshua, it's confusing indeed. So usually Shopify uses liquid code but for this post-purchase script because it fires in a sandbox for security reasons it uses pure javascript. I am experienced with doing all of this in liquid code. I will send you links to the lineitem.product and product.tags doc (it's in liquid code but I'm bringing it into Javascript or trying too)

Comment: line_item.product -> https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/line_item?shpxid=39a38d5c-4FC8-4C69-DC83-5B48153CBE96#line_item-product

Comment: product.tags -> https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product#product-tags

Comment: @david thanks for all your hard work. So within each "LineItem" we should see a "product" and in each "product" we should have "tags". This is how it works in liquid code. The doc is very confusing.

Comment: @JackTrowbridge: Hopefully this ends up working.  I'd be mindful of the rest of their documentation as well.  Basically any time you get this error it just means that the property from which you were reading was `undefined`, so the first step would always be to `console.log` that parent object and see what's there.

Comment: Hi David, you were right about there not being any tag variable being available. It is there in liquid code but not in this setup Shopify has put together. I confirmed this using console.log. So I have resorted to saving the tags into a cookie on the cart page and then accessing these as I need to. Other than that, your answer is right when it comes to Javascript and properly "ForEaching" through an array. So I've learned when it's an array, you, of course, need to for each it or the equivalent before trying to get data from inside it. Thank you.

Comment: P.S. The documentation is indeed wrong too. It should be "LineItems". I did confirm this part. That defo did confuse me